# Is it possible to count the number of partitions?

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

I am working on a test in which I must find out the number of partitions of a table and check if it is right. If I use `show partitions TableName` I get all the partitions by name, but I wish to get the number of partitions, like something along the lines `show count(partitions) TableName` (which retuns OK btw.. so it's not good) and get 12 (for ex.).

 Is there any way to achieve this??

Comment: Often a table can be represented as a set of tuples, and the number of partitions of a set is called a [Bell number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_number).

Answer (score 6):

Using [Hive CLI](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Cli)

```
$ hive --silent -e "show partitions <dbName>.<tableName>;" | wc -l
```

> --silent is to enable silent mode
>
> -e tells hive to execute quoted query string

Comment: No command, no direct way to do it?   About Spark accessing Hive, some command.

Answer (score 3):

You could use:

```
select count(distinct <partition key>) from <TableName>;
```

Comment: I did try that but with no result :((

Comment: With this command, hive will go all rows, find the distinct/unique partition key and finally count them. As you can imagine, this can be very slow. It would be faster to count it from 'show partitions <TableName>;' but I haven't found a way for doing this.

Answer (score 1):

By using the below command, you will get the all partitions and also at the end it shows the number of fetched rows. That number of rows means number of partitions

SHOW PARTITIONS [db_name.]table_name [PARTITION(partition_spec)];

< failed pictoral example >

Answer (score 0):

You can use the WebHCat interface to get information like this. This has the benefit that you can run the command from anywhere that the server is accessible. The result is JSON - use a JSON parser of your choice to process the results.

In this example of piping the WebHCat results to Python, only the number 24 is returned representing the number of partitions for this table. (Server name is the name node).

```
curl -s 'http://*myservername*:50111/templeton/v1/ddl/database/*mydatabasename*/table/*mytablename*/partition?user.name=*myusername*' | python -c 'import sys, json; print len(json.load(sys.stdin)["partitions"])'
24
```

Answer (score 0):

In scala you can do following:

```
sql("show partitions <table_name>").count()
```

Comment: Below question is related to hive and not spark on hive... above answer will work only if one working on hive using spark.

Answer (score 0):

I used following.
`beeline -silent --showHeader=false --outputformat=csv2 -e 'show partitions <dbname>.<tablename>' | wc -l`

Comment: What does this add to [Viswa Murali's 2017 answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44605072)?

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is very old, but still if anyone is looking for the answer, here is the query.

```
select count(distinct <partition_column>) as partition_count from <db>.<table_name>;
```

Answer (score -3):

Use the following syntax:

```
show create table <table name>;
```